# Select DISTINCT on one column that returns multiple columns using more than one table

Tags: sql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT dtljob.lj_jobnum, dtbom2.b2_id,dtbom2.b2_ljid
FROM dtbom2, dtljob
WHERE dtbom2.b2_ljid = dtljob.lj_id
ORDER BY dtbom2.b2_id DESC
```

Here are my results:

```
lj_jobnum   b2_id   b2_ljid
201302867   230     150
201302867   229     150
201302807   228      87
201302807   227      87
201402911   226     200
201402911   225     200
201403027   224     320
201403027   222     320
```

My problem is that I only want to see unique records for li_jobnum and b2_ljid, and I need to have the result `order by b2_id desc` in order to get the most recent record to the top of the result.

Based on the data above, here is what I would like my result to be:

```
lj_jobnum   b2_id   b2_ljid
201302867   230     150
201302807   228      87
201402911   226     200
201403027   224     320
```

I really do not need the b2_id in my results as long as the results are ordered by b2_id desc.

How can I change my query to get the results I need?

Comment: So you just want the MAX b2_ID  you need to use aggregate functions

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the max b2_Id an aggregate function would work.  These necessitate group by statements.  I also aliased the tables to make them a bit easier to read.

```
SELECT  b.lj_jobnum, max(a.b2_id) max_b2_ID, a.b2_ljid  
FROM dtbom2 a, dtljob b
WHERE  a.b2_ljid = b.lj_id
GROUP BY b.lj_jobnum, a.b2_ljid 
ORDER BY  max_b2_ID desc
```

OR (using more modern join syntax)

```
SELECT  b.lj_jobnum, max(a.b2_id) max_B2_ID, a.b2_ljid  
FROM dtbom2 a
INNER JOIN dtljob b
  ON a.b2_ljid = b.lj_id
GROUP BY b.lj_jobnum, a.b2_ljid 
ORDER BY  max_b2_id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an aggregate function then.  You need to decide how to handle having multiple b2_id as in the case of 
(201302867   , 150) where you have 2 b2_ids of (229, 230)

It looks like you just want the Max of the 2 and order it.

So your query could look something like this.

```
Select  lj_jobnum, b2_ljid
from dtbom2, dtljob 
Where   dtbom2.b2_ljid = dtljob.lj_id
Group By lj_jobnum, b2_ljid
Order by Max(b2_id) Desc
```

The Group By will create distinct sets of the columns in the clause.  Any columns you want to use NOT in the group by clause you will need to use an aggregate function on.  The common ones are Max, Min, Avg, Count